# Let $X$ be a distribution over $N$ (the set of non-negative numbers), with mass $P(X=i) = \frac{a}{2^i}$ . (More details in discription)

Tags: probability, expected-value

This question consists of $4 $ parts in which the first part of calculating $a$ has been done by me and my answer is $1/2$.
The second part asks to find the $E[X]$ i.e.-

> $$\sum_{i=0}^n i*P(i)$$

According to my calculation the answer is $0$, but unfortunately, it's not correct.
Can anybody help me with this?
The two more parts which I am unable to solve are-
$P[Y=1]$ , where $Y=Xmod3$ 
$$E[Y]$$

Comment: Non negative numbers,  do you mean positive integers?

Comment: How on earth could the sum of positive numbers be $0$?

Comment: @dmtri yes positive integers including 0

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I applied the convergence method... the series is monotonically decreasing ..so converged to 0. But now yes you are righnt it cannot be 0.

Answer (score 0):

A small hint for one of the parts. You're looking for something like this:
$$\sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{n}{2^{n+1}} = 
\frac{1}{4} \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{n}{2^{n-1}}$$
To calculate it, first, find out what is $f(x)$ here:
$$f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty n x^{n-1}$$
Notice that the initial sum is equal to $\frac{1}{4} f\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$ and that 
$f(x) = g'(x)$ where $g(x) = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty x^n$.